# Al importar una tabla dentro de un método, no reconoce los valores de su interior

Tags: java, condiciones

Tengo este metodo:

```
    static char[] destapar(char[] tabla, char[]t, int pos) {
        char[] tabla2 = Arrays.copyOf(tabla, tabla.length);
        
        if(t[pos]==0) {
            for(int j = 0; t[pos] == t[pos+j];j++) {
             tabla2[pos+j] = t[pos+j];
            tabla2[pos+j+1] = t[pos+j+1];
           }
           for(int j = 0; t[pos] == t[pos-j];j++) {
             tabla2[pos-j] = t[pos-j];
            tabla2[pos+j-1] = t[pos+j-1];
           }
        }
        else if(t[pos]==1) {
            for(int j = 0; t[pos] == t[pos+j];j++) {
             tabla2[pos+j] = t[pos+j];
           }
           for(int j = 0; t[pos] == t[pos-j];j++) {
             tabla2[pos-j] = t[pos-j];
           }
        }
           else {
               tabla2[pos] = t[pos];
           }
        return tabla2;
    }
```

El problema que tengo es que da igual si en el valor de `t[pos]` coincide con 0 o 1 que siempre se mete en el `else`

Declaración de variables:

- `tabla` es un array de clase `char` de 20 celdas
- `t` es un array de clase `char` de 20 celdas
- `tabla2` es la copia de `tabla`
- `pos` es la posición indicada por el jugador

He probado:

- Copiando ambas tablas dentro del metodo
- Copiando solo una de ellas
- Sin copiarlas

Comment: Parece que, asumes que ya sabemos cuál es el objetivo de tu código.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resuelto:

```
        char[] tabla2 = Arrays.copyOf(tabla, tabla.length);
        
        if(t[pos]=='0') {
            for(int j = 0; t[pos] == t[pos+j];j++) {
             tabla2[pos+j] = t[pos+j];
            tabla2[pos+j+1] = t[pos+j+1];
           }
           for(int j = 0; t[pos] == t[pos-j];j++) {
             tabla2[pos-j] = t[pos-j];
            tabla2[pos+j-1] = t[pos+j-1];
           }
        }
        else if(t[pos]=='1') {
            for(int j = 0; t[pos] == t[pos+j];j++) {
             tabla2[pos+j] = t[pos+j];
           }
           for(int j = 0; t[pos] == t[pos-j];j++) {
             tabla2[pos-j] = t[pos-j];
           }
        }
           else {
               tabla2[pos] = t[pos];
           }
        return tabla2;
    }
```

El problema es que en el `if` y el `else if`, estás comparando `t[pos]` con 0 y 1, pero en ambos casos deberías comparar `t[pos]` con el carácter '0' y '1', respectivamente.